# My ListView doesn't show anything

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, sqliteopenhelper

I fetch data from sqlite in Lists to show them up into a fragment's ListView. I first created the ListView in the layout, it didn't work since Android Studio didn't find my ListView based on the id. Then I created the ListView programmatically and it shows nothing. The weird point is, enter code herein another fragment where i did the same, everything works perfectly.

My question is: Can you guys check if there is a mistake into my code or tell me what is going wrong there ?
I've tried everything i knew so far as a newbie but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Find attached parts of coding related this program. I'm working with a fragment navigation drawer...

**Main Fragment**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import cm.opep.opep.DatabaseHelper;
import cm.opep.opep.R;
import cm.opep.opep.transfert.DbResponse;
import cm.opep.opep.transfert.DbTrajet;
import cm.opep.opep.transfert.PassagerAdapter;

public class DetailTrajetFragment extends Fragment {

    DatabaseHelper helper;
    PassagerAdapter ListAdapter;
    String et_iduser, et_idchauffeur, et_idtrajet, et_placesvoulues, et_rechercheDateD, et_rechercheHeureH, et_rechercheVilleA, et_rechercheVilleD;

    ArrayList<String> prenom_passager_arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> age_passager_arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> niveau_passager_arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> id_passager_arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_trajet, container, false);
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        getActivity().setTitle(String.valueOf("ID Trajet: " + getArguments().getString("idtrajet")));
        initUI(v);
        return v;
    }

    public void initUI(View v) {

        final TextView cptevilledepart = v.findViewById(R.id.propositionvilledepart);
        final TextView cptelieudepart = v.findViewById(R.id.cpte_lieudepart);
        final TextView cptedatedepart = v.findViewById(R.id.propositionDateD);
        final TextView cptedatearrivee = v.findViewById(R.id.cpte_date_arrivee);
        final TextView cpteheuredepart = v.findViewById(R.id.propositionHeureD);
        final TextView cptetaillebagage = v.findViewById(R.id.propositionbagage);
        final TextView cpteflexibilite = v.findViewById(R.id.flexibilite);
        final TextView cptedetour = v.findViewById(R.id.detour);
        final TextView cpteprix = v.findViewById(R.id.cpte_prix);
        final TextView cptecommentairechauffeur = v.findViewById(R.id.cpte_commentaire_chauffeur);
        final TextView cpteplacesdisponibles = v.findViewById(R.id.cpte_places_disponibles);
        final TextView cptevillearrivee = v.findViewById(R.id.propositionvillearrivee);
        final TextView cptelieudepot = v.findViewById(R.id.cpte_lieu_depot);
        final TextView cpteprenom = v.findViewById(R.id.prenom_chauffeur);
        final TextView cpteage = v.findViewById(R.id.age_chauffeur);
        final TextView cpteniveau = v.findViewById(R.id.niveau_chauffeur);
        Button bouton_reserver = v.findViewById(R.id.bouton_réserver);
        final TextView vide = v.findViewById(R.id.vide);

        ListView liste_passag = new ListView(this.getActivity());
        int i = 1226;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, i, 0, 0);
        liste_passag.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, i + 75, 0, 0);
        vide.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        et_iduser = getArguments().getString("id");
        et_idchauffeur = getArguments().getString("idchauffeur");
        et_idtrajet = getArguments().getString("idtrajet");
        et_placesvoulues = getArguments().getString("placesvoulues");
        et_rechercheVilleD = getArguments().getString("VilleDepart");
        et_rechercheVilleA = getArguments().getString("VilleArrivee");
        et_rechercheHeureH = getArguments().getString("Heure");
        et_rechercheDateD = getArguments().getString("Date");

        prenom_passager_arrayList.clear();
        id_passager_arrayList.clear();
        niveau_passager_arrayList.clear();
        age_passager_arrayList.clear();

        ArrayList<String> prenom_passager_arrayList = helper.getTrajetPrenomPassager(et_idtrajet);
        ArrayList<String> id_passager_arrayList = helper.getTrajetIDPassager(et_idtrajet);
        ArrayList<String> niveau_passager_arrayList = helper.getTrajetNiveauPassager(et_idtrajet);
        ArrayList<String> age_passager_arrayList = helper.getTrajetAgePassager(et_idtrajet);

        ListAdapter = new PassagerAdapter(this.getActivity(),
                prenom_passager_arrayList,
                id_passager_arrayList,
                niveau_passager_arrayList,
                age_passager_arrayList
        );
        liste_passag.setAdapter(ListAdapter);
        liste_passag.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View child, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
}
```

**Adapter**

```
package cm.opep.opep.transfert;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import cm.opep.opep.R;


public class PassagerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context contxt;
    private ArrayList<String> prenom;
    private ArrayList<String> idpassager;
    private ArrayList<String> niveau;
    private ArrayList<String> age;
    //private ArrayList<String> avis;
    //private ArrayList<String> note;

    public PassagerAdapter(Context context1, ArrayList<String> et_prenom, ArrayList<String> et_idpassager, ArrayList<String> et_niveau, ArrayList<String> et_age) {
        this.contxt = context1;
        this.prenom = et_prenom;
        this.idpassager = et_idpassager;
        this.niveau = et_niveau;
        this.age = et_age;
        //this.avis = et_avis;
        //this.note = et_note;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return prenom.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View child, ViewGroup parent) {

        Holder holder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        if(child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) contxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            assert layoutInflater != null;
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_resultat_recherche_passager, parent,false);

            holder = new Holder();
            holder.pranom = child.findViewById(R.id.prenom_passager);
            holder.idpassenger = child.findViewById(R.id.idpassager);
            holder.niv = child.findViewById(R.id.niveau_passager);
            holder.old = child.findViewById(R.id.age_passager);
            //holder.mind= child.findViewById(R.id.avis_passager);
            //holder.rank= child.findViewById(R.id.note_passager);
            child.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }
        holder.pranom.setText(prenom.get(position));
        holder.idpassenger.setText(idpassager.get(position));
        holder.niv.setText(niveau.get(position));
        holder.old.setText(age.get(position));
        //holder.mind.setText(avis.get(position));
        //holder.rank.setText(note.get(position));
        return child;
    }
    public class Holder {

        TextView pranom;
        TextView niv;
        TextView old;
        //TextView mind;
        TextView idpassenger;
        //TextView rank;
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHelper**

```
public ArrayList<String> getTrajetPrenomPassager(String et_idtrajet) {
    ArrayList<String> prenom_passager_arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME11 + " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_NAME1 + " ON " + COLUMN_ID_PASSAGER + " = " + COLUMN_ID_USER + " WHERE (" + COLUMN_ID_TRAJET + " = '" + et_idtrajet + "' AND " + COLUMN_VALIDATION_RESERVATION + " != 'Invalidé' AND " + COLUMN_DATE_ANNULATION_DU_PASSAGER + " IS NULL) ORDER BY " + COLUMN_DATE_DE_RESERVATION + " ASC";
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            prenom_passager_arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PRENOM)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
    return prenom_passager_arrayList;
}

public ArrayList<String> getTrajetIDPassager(String et_idtrajet) {
    ArrayList<String> id_passager_arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME11 + " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_NAME1 + " ON " + COLUMN_ID_PASSAGER + " = " + COLUMN_ID_USER + " WHERE (" + COLUMN_ID_TRAJET + " = '" + et_idtrajet + "' AND " + COLUMN_VALIDATION_RESERVATION + " != 'Invalidé' AND " + COLUMN_DATE_ANNULATION_DU_PASSAGER + " IS NULL) ORDER BY " + COLUMN_DATE_DE_RESERVATION + " ASC";
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            id_passager_arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID_PASSAGER)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
    return id_passager_arrayList;
}

public ArrayList<String> getTrajetNiveauPassager(String et_idtrajet) {
    ArrayList<String> niveau_passager_arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME11 + " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_NAME1 + " ON " + COLUMN_ID_PASSAGER + " = " + COLUMN_ID_USER + " WHERE (" + COLUMN_ID_TRAJET + " = '" + et_idtrajet + "' AND " + COLUMN_VALIDATION_RESERVATION + " != 'Invalidé' AND " + COLUMN_DATE_ANNULATION_DU_PASSAGER + " IS NULL) ORDER BY " + COLUMN_DATE_DE_RESERVATION + " ASC";
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            niveau_passager_arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NIVEAU)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
    return niveau_passager_arrayList;
}

public ArrayList<String> getTrajetAgePassager(String et_idtrajet) {
    ArrayList<String> age_passager_arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME11 + " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_NAME1 + " ON " + COLUMN_ID_PASSAGER + " = " + COLUMN_ID_USER + " WHERE (" + COLUMN_ID_TRAJET + " = '" + et_idtrajet + "' AND " + COLUMN_VALIDATION_RESERVATION + " != 'Invalidé' AND " + COLUMN_DATE_ANNULATION_DU_PASSAGER + " IS NULL) ORDER BY " + COLUMN_DATE_DE_RESERVATION + " ASC";
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            age_passager_arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_AGE)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
    return age_passager_arrayList;
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: @GVillani82 I populated data into the database and actually it has to fetch some of them when i run the app. I know the problem is not from my request because when i fetch data through a textview it shows those data. But when i fetch through an arraylist i get nothing at all like my database was empty...

Comment: Anyone to help me out ?